# Выполнение долгого php скрипта через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, клиент-сервер

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при выполнение php скрипта (скрипт больше минуты выполняется) сервер намертво зависает и обратиться к нему у с клиента, который запустил скрипт нельзя, пока скрипт не завершит свою работу.
Скрипт запускается по средствам нажатия пользователем кнопки (Ajax).
Как мне сделать так, чтобы сервер продолжал выполнять скрипт в фоновом режиме и не зависал для клиента?
Я рассматривал вариант Pthreads, но еще не пробовал, не знаю, имеет ли это смысл.

**Обновление #1**

Начал копать в сторону PHP-FPM, но нужно разбираться в настройке, решил отложить на будущее, решение достаточно хорошее и мне понравилось. Время у меня поджимает, нашел в интернете функцию:

```
function exec_script($url, $params = array())
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);

    if (!$fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $data = http_build_query($params, '', '&');

    fwrite($fp, "POST " . (!empty($parts['path']) ? $parts['path'] : '/') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Host: " . $parts['host'] . "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);

    return true;
}

exec_script('http://example.com/b.php', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

Думаю создать класс AsyncExecutor или что-то в этом духе и использовать данный метод. Быстро и сердито, так сказать. Если есть более элегантное и лучшее решение - пишите, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: ну вообще есть такой слово как "асинхронный". вот и запрос ajax  должен быть таковым.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так вот в этом и вопрос. Какой механизм для этого использовать? Куда мне нужно копать, чтобы решить данную проблему?

Comment: Вообще, если у вас любой пользователь может запустить такой долгий скрипт - нужно задуматься, что сделано не так. Может сам скрипт всё же оптимизировать? В 99% случаев это решение намного лучше, чем насиловать бедный сервер.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский смс и емейл рассылка, где формируются акты и счета, я бы и рад оптимизировать, но было бы что. Видимо, мой случай как раз входит в этот 1% :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, стандартных решений несколько. Выбирать, какой лучше в конкретно вашем случае - исходя из совокупности факторов.

Клиент, кроме результата выполнения запроса, должен уметь принимать ответ вроде "еще не готово, ждите", и корректно реагировать на него (показывать анимацию, повторять запрос через Х секунд).

А вот как быть на стороне сервера - вариантов несколько:

1. pcntl_fork() - эта функция позволяет "раздвоить" процесс выполнения скрипта в некой точке, после чего один процесс должен отдать клиенту ответ "ждите", а второй - начать выполнять долгую операцию, предварительно избавившись от временного лимита - ste_time_limit(0), а также, установив некий флаг "процесс выполняется" (в текстовом файле на сервере, в БД, еще где-нибудь, где данные не теряются в конце выполнения скрипта). А по окончании выполнения - туда же сохранить результаты.
   При повторном запросе, скрипт должен сначала заглянуть в этот флаг "выполняется процесс". Если выполняется - сразу отдает "ждите", если не выполняется и результаты сохранены - отдать результаты. Если ни того ни другого - значит надо запускать процесс.
2. серверный скрипт (которого опрашивают ajax-ом) вообще не выполняет тяжелый запрос, а только записывает "задание для выполнения", и возвращает либо "ждите", либо "готово". А тяжелой работой занимается отдельный скрипт в фоне, который поднимается по крону, смотрит в БД, и если там есть задача - начинает ее выполнять (точно так же, в базе пометив "эта задача выполняется" / "эта задача выполнена и вот результат).

Comment: Вот! Примерно то, что нужно. У меня в базе реализован статус выполнения скрипта, я уже реализовал этот механизм, проблема была только в том, как запустить еще один поток, в котором выполнялся бы скрипт. Первое решение мне подходит, спасибо!

Comment: ну, коли первое, то сразу обратите внимание на типичные грабли, чтобы не наступить: 1. не забываем убивать зомби, 2. осторожнее с дескрипторами, открытыми до форка (коннекты с БД, файлы, потоковые дескрипторы и т.п.), 3. таймаут выполнения длинной задачи; иногда форкнутый процесс залипает в каком-то дедлоке, который черт его знает откуда взялся... вобщем, надо учитывать, что иногда он будет залипать, ну и убивать/перезапускать/сообщать юзеру и т.п., по желанию)

Comment: ну а вообще, конечно, форк - это больше костыльный вариант, с кучей подводных камней. демон, или периодически запускаемый по крону скрипт - архитектурно более верно. к тому же, более стабильно и понятно в плане кода, т.к. скрипты при выполнении изолированы друг от друга и не мешают друг другу работать, в отличие от форка.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос!!!

У браузеров есть ограничение, обычно 4-5 запросов к одному домену.
Если у вас на этом домене есть "тяжелый" скрипт, который выполняется долго, то браузер поставит его в очередь, дальнейшие запросы "лехкие" так же будут висеть, ожидая завершение тяжелого запроса

Можно это обойти, поставим этот "тяжелый" скрипт на другой домен, или же через alias, так что бы URL домена сменился.

Для теста накидал скрипт, для эмуляции этого поведения

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="test(1)">Кнопка1 - тяжелый другой домен</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="test(2)">Кнопка2 - тяжелый текущий домен</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="test(0)">Кнопка0 - лехгий текущий домен</button>
```

**JS**

```
function test(param) {
    let options = {
        url : 'http://example.com/test.phtml', // Текущий домен
        data : {param : param},
        type : 'POST',
        success : function () {
            console.log('success');
        }
    };

    if (param == 1) {
        options.url = 'http://www.example.com/test.phtml' // Другой домен
    }

    $.ajax(options);
}
```

**PHP : test.phtml**

```
<?php
// для крос запроса
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$param = $_REQUEST['param'];

if ($param == 1) {
    // Имитации тяжелого запроса (Другой сервер)
    sleep(5);
} else if ($param == 2) {
    // Имитации тяжелого запроса (текущий сервер)
    sleep(5);
} else {
    // быстрое выполение
}
```

Если по кликать по кнопке Кнопка2 несколько раз, а далее по Кнопке0, то вы будите ждать выполнение.
А если такое же проделать Кнопка1 и Кнопка0, то ждать не будите

Comment: Нет, это точно не из-за браузера. Видимо, всему виной мой код, который выполняется в одном потоке и из-за этого происходит такое поведение. На клиенте показывается прелоадер и всё. Как я уже написал, использую ajax.

Comment: @MarkKhromov обновил ответ, посмотрите, правильно ли я вас понял

Comment: Посмотрел, решение неплохое, если оно работает, то очень круто, но мне нужно сделать в контексте текущего домена, сроки поджимают, да и ресурсы выделять на поднятие другого домена, настройку и оплату не очень хочется, сами понимаете. Поднял вам рейтинг, не знаю, кто -1 поставил :-(
В любом случае, спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: @MarkKhromov Так вы можете добавить алиас, для текущего домена, и нечего поднимать не нужно